# Rails - including a search field in a new object form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Users and Books - Users can be Contributors on Books.

```
User has_many :contributions
Book has_many :contributions
Contribution belongs_to :user, belongs_to :book
```

I have a new contribution form - /contributions/new.html.erb and a problem: I want to use a search field for the user, but the submit_tag for search field is submitting the whole form. The code I have is below. How do I make the search submit_tag just operate on the search field?

```
<h1>New contribution</h1>

<%= form_for(@contribution) do |f| %>
  <% if @contribution.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contribution.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contribution from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @contribution.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
     <%= f.select :contribtype, options_for_select(Contribution::CONTRIB_TYPES) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    <% if @users %>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <%= render partial: 'layouts/bookshelf', locals: {user: user} %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :book_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :book_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>`
```

Comment: Why do you put your search field in your create contribution form? What do that search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Forms**

The reason you're "submitting the whole form" is because of [how HTML handles forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Whenever you "submit" a form, it will use the metadata in its parent `<form>` tag to send your data to your server endpoint. The problem you have is that you're trying to create a form within a form, which simply won't work

The solution will be to use `Ajax` to handle the `search` functionality separately:

---

**Ajax**

```
#your_form
<%= form_for(@contribution) do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: "search" %>
   <%= link_to "Search", contribution_search_path, it: "search_submit" %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

You'll have to style the "Search" link as a remote ajax request - allowing you to send the params to your server:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
$(document).on("click", "a#search_submit", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      data: {query: $("#search").val() },
      success: function(data) {
         // do what you want here
      }
   });
});
```

This will allow you to [process the "search" request asynchronously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to the scope of your page loading, bypassing the HTML form issue, and consequently providing you with the functionality you require

---

**Update**

The path issue will be caused by my reference to a path which likely doesn't exist. You'll have to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :contributions
   get :search, on: :collection
end
```

If you do this & let me know the result of `rake routes`, I'll be in a much more robust position to help you!

Comment: Hi Rich - thanks very much for this. As you may have intimated, I'm a little out of my depth here. I've added the code you've suggested, and am getting an error on the second line in the view - undefined NameError: local variable or method `contributions_search_path'. I've edited the line to read 'link_to "Search", contributions_search_path, id: "search_submit" - I thought that might be the problem, but to no avail - I have contributions listed as a resource in my routes, should I add something there? Many thanks

Comment: Hey bud, thanks for letting me know! The problem will be that I made up the route as a placeholder for you - let me update the answer to reflect what you need to look at

Comment: -- it's probably worth mentioning I've not added the // do something  element yet, other than to call an alert to show it's working.

Comment: - the search route is search_contributions GET    /contributions/search(.:format)   contributions#search

Comment: Actually, I've got that wrong. I thought that this problem was solved, and that the next one was unrelated, so I closed this off, but I think I still have a patching issue - but given that your answer is to the problem of submitting search in a form without submitting the form, I'm going to close this off anyway - thanks for your help :)